# php $this->variable in a function not working like I hoped

Tags: php, variables, this

I'm learning PHP and reading through a Robin Nixon book. I'm having trouble with this code:

```
<?php 
class Centre
{
    public $centre_name; // String: The name of the centre
    public $tagline; // String: The centre's tagline

        // Set the centres details. This will later be done through a form.
    function set_details()
    {
        $this->centre_name = "YMCA";
        $this->tagline = "Lets all go to the Y";
    }

        // Display the centres details. 
    function display()
    {
        echo "Centre Name - " . $centre->centre_name . "<br />";
        echo "Centre Tagline - " . $centre->tagline . "<br />";
    }
} 

?>

<?php 
    $centre = new Centre();
    $centre->set_details();
    $centre->display();
?>
```

Right now this is outputing:
Centre Name - 
Centre Tagline - 
So the variables are being set. Am I using $this->variable = "whatever"; correctly?

Comment: Your `display` function must use `$this` instead of `$centre`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this

```
function display()
{
    echo "Centre Name - " . $centre->centre_name . "<br />";
    echo "Centre Tagline - " . $centre->tagline . "<br />";
}
```

to

```
function display()
{
    echo "Centre Name - " . $this->centre_name . "<br />";
    echo "Centre Tagline - " . $this->tagline . "<br />";
}
```

you used `$centre` instead of `$this`.

Comment: Ahh... how did I miss that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function dispaly() like this :

Inside your class you can access variables with `$this`

```
 function display()
    {
        echo "Centre Name - " . $this->centre_name . "<br />";
        echo "Centre Tagline - " . $this->tagline . "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do, but replace "center" by "this" in display() :

```
function display()
{
    echo "Centre Name - " . $this->centre_name . "<br />";
    echo "Centre Tagline - " . $this->tagline . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Change `$thi->tagline` to `$this->tagline`